# Upload Excel file to Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm simply trying to upload excel.xlsx file with Python panda package so i can tokenize the text. I tried for hours but nothing works. Any help will be great:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = open(r'''C:\Users\farid-PC\Desktop\Tester.xlsx''', errors 
='ignore')
movies = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
movies.head()
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/farid-PC/PycharmProjects/fake_news/fault.py", line 4, in <module>
    movies = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
  File "C:\Users\farid-PC\PycharmProjects\fake_news\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\farid-PC\PycharmProjects\fake_news\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\farid-PC\PycharmProjects\fake_news\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 307, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\farid-PC\PycharmProjects\fake_news\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 392, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
  File "C:\Users\farid-PC\PycharmProjects\fake_news\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 162, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Users\farid-PC\PycharmProjects\fake_news\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 91, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Users\farid-PC\PycharmProjects\fake_news\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1267, in getbof
    opcode = self.get2bytes()
  File "C:\Users\farid-PC\PycharmProjects\fake_news\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 672, in get2bytes
    return (BYTES_ORD(hi) << 8) | BYTES_ORD(lo)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Did you try: `movies = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\farid-PC\Desktop\Tester.xlsx')`? It should not make any difference, but, just a try.

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: this is the error i get now. What is an easy way to upload excel file for text based data manipulation in python?

Comment: Check my updated comment. Just put an `r` before it

Comment: i got it to work. I used \\ instead of \.

Comment: @user3658513: Generally, I find it a good idea to prefer `/` to \\ in paths for just this reason. Both work in Python.

Comment: You can write your (own) solution which solved your issue in answer and accept that.